# Proving $max\{|x_1|,...,|x_n|\}$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=max\{|x_1|,...,|x_n|\}$. Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

I have to show that for any $\epsilon >0$, I can find a positive $\delta$ such that $\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+...+(x_n-y_n)^2} < \delta$ implies $||x_m|-|y_k||<\epsilon$, where $x_m$ and $y_n$ are the greatest (in absolute value) among the coordinates of $x$ and $y$ respectively. I know I need to find an inequality between $\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+...+(x_n-y_n)^2}$ and $||x_m|-|y_k||$, but I can't find it.

Comment: Hint: Since for any vector $z$ and index $i$ it is true that $||z|| \geq |z_i|$, we have that $||x-y|| \lt \delta$ implies $\max(|x_i - y_i|) < \delta$.

Comment: @Arthur I see that. We also have $||x_m|-|y_k|| \leq |x_m-y_k|$. How do I relate $max |x_i-y_i|$ with $|x_m-y_k|$?